# put two cards side by side with tailwind

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I am doing a practice project to learn new technologies like tailwind which is the first time I use it, I want it to be side by side without overlapping.

example of how it is currently being over-used

[image]

How can I do it?

```html
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1 class="text-4xl text-center">Task</h1>
    
    <div class="grid grid-cols-12 p-4">
      <div class="col-span-9 m-4">
        <span>
                    <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Escribe una tarea"
                            class="input input-bordered w-full"
                            v-model="task"
                            @keyup.enter="addTask"
                            id="task_input" />
                    </span>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-span-3 m-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addTask" id="task_button">
          Agregar
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4" id="cardContainer">
        <div class="card min-w-0 max-w-md">
          <div class="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl" id="task_card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">Card title!</h2>
              
              <p id="task_text" class="text-base-content">
                If a dog chews shoes whose shoes does he choose?
              </p>
              
              <div class="card-actions justify-end">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <!-- <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

Comment: Share the whole code, plz. Typically, cards don't overlap each other. It looks really weird.

Comment: Just share the code inside div "cardContainer". It must be a grid related issue.

Comment: I'll put the code right away

Comment: I see two cards on the image, but there is only one card on your code.

Comment: in the image I put it as an example but if you want I can add the other card in the code it will still look like in the picture

Comment: If the `cardContainer` div is wide enough to fit two cards, it won't happen.

Comment: did not work, one on top of the other

Comment: That means `cardContainer` div is smaller than the sum of two cards width (plus gap).
Add w-250 class to `cardContainer` div and try once more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two css classes that are not tailwind, **card** and c**ard-actions**, so it is not easy to fully help you out without knowing those classes css, but it looks like you have a new grid wrapping around every card and that div does not have any cols-span definition related to the main grid wrapper above. So you need to tell it how many span to take up, like this, for 3 span on every row (12/4 = 3), add: **col-span-4**

Code:

```
<div class=" col-span-4  grid grid-cols-3 gap-4" id="cardContainer">
        <div class="card min-w-0 max-w-md">
...
```

Comment: I put col-span-12 and it worked

Comment: Yes, if you want one card per row.  Glad I could help out.